# finding Search result Position using selenium and python

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver

Here is the link to the web page.

https://shop.techdata.com/

When I run following code it executes successfully

---

```
import pip


package_name = 'selenium'
pip.main(['install', package_name])

from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\All\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
#Chromedriver is needed on your machine  but sometimes webdriver.Chrome() works as well
driver.get('https://shop.techdata.com/')

driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)

driver.find_element_by_id("quickSearchBox").send_keys("printer")

driver.find_element_by_id("quickSearch").click()
```

---

and I get following webpage as a result which is success:

https://shop.techdata.com/searchall?b=1&kw=printer

---

My problem starts here
Now in the appeared search result, I want to get the position of all printers by the company named EPSON(It is appearing at 14th 15th and 16th position)

so I did following intersection but the output set is null.

---

```
search_elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('productContent')

EPSON_elements = driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text('EPSON')


print('search_elements',search_elements)
print('EPSON_elements>',EPSON_elements)
elements = set(search_elements).intersection(set(EPSON_elements))
print('Common elements>', elements)
```

When I am printing search elements and epson elements, the count there is corret. It is giving 25 search element and 3 epson element which I checked manually and its correct but now it is unable to find the intersection and output of comon elements is set null.

So the question I have is.. how do I find this position as 8th,9th and 10th?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One element that is common to all of the printers is the anchor with `class` `productDetailsLink`. Find the collection of these and then look for those that contain 'EPSON' as their `text`.

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> driver = webdriver.Chrome()
>>> driver.get('https://shop.techdata.com/searchall?b=1&kw=printer')
>>> items = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('productDetailsLink')
>>> len(items)
25
>>> for i, item in enumerate(items):
...     if 'EPSON' in item.text:
...         i, item.text
... 
(7, 'EPSON WORKFORCE PRO WF-4740 - MULTIFUNCTION PRINTER (COLOR)')
(8, 'EPSON WORKFORCE PRO WF-4730 - MULTIFUNCTION PRINTER (COLOR)')
(9, 'EPSON WORKFORCE PRO WF-3720 - MULTIFUNCTION PRINTER (COLOR)')
```

Edit, responding to comments:

This code includes the earlier requirement, to search for the printers page. It does **not** include arrangements needed to wait for the first page to load fully.

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> driver = webdriver.Chrome()
>>> driver.get('https://shop.techdata.com/')
>>> driver.find_element_by_id("quickSearchBox").send_keys("printer")
>>> driver.find_element_by_id("quickSearch").click()
>>> items = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('productDetailsLink')
>>> len(items)
25
>>> for i, item in enumerate(items):
...     if 'EPSON' in item.text:
...         i, item.text
...         
(7, 'EPSON WORKFORCE PRO WF-4740 - MULTIFUNCTION PRINTER (COLOR)')
(8, 'EPSON WORKFORCE PRO WF-4730 - MULTIFUNCTION PRINTER (COLOR)')
(9, 'EPSON WORKFORCE PRO WF-3720 - MULTIFUNCTION PRINTER (COLOR)')
```

Comment: Hi, Thank but I tried doing this earlier . It returns only one output everytime... the link which you have used is different. It doesn't search the keywords/ I am a new to python so I am finding it difficult to understand>>>>>>(24, HP OFFICEJET PRO 8710 ALL-IN-ONE - MULTIFUNCTION PRINTER (COLOR))

Comment: I suspect you used `find_element_by_class_name` rather than `find_elements_by_class_name`. Is that possible?

Comment: I see now. I left the part out where you search for keywords because you already knew how to do that.

Comment: `quickSearchBox` has to have become visible for you to send keys to it. For this you can see 'Expected conditions' at http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html and follow the link labelled 'Convenience methods'. I think there's one you can use there.

Comment: Hi Sir, Can you take a look at another issue I am working on? >>>>>>>>> Append python output as a block/row in existing Excel file

Comment: I would consider it except that I don't have Excel.

Comment: Okay!I am having hard time in deciding which Excel module should I use? I can't see one which doesn't have a limitation.

Comment: I can't offer any advice at all. If a question about this proves unwelcome here on SO you could try on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. How about thisone ,sir? >>>>>>>>>>>>>No error but no output for in automating search process in selenium python

Answer (score 0):

You could change the key 'printer' to 'epson printer'

Comment: But that will result only EPSON printers... I want to list all and then find where my product stands